# Google App Script event value type for date field different from e.value and e.range.getValue()

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I've just started messing around with Google Apps Script and found something that has me puzzled. I have a spreadsheet with a cell A2 that contains a date. I have created an onEdit() event handler.

If I change the date value, `e.value` is a number, which is the number of days since 1/1/1900. `e.range.getValue()` is a date.

Here's a simple example:

```
function onEdit(e) {
   // This returns a number -- number of days since 1/1/1900
   SpreadsheetApp.getUi().alert('From event: '+e.value); 

   // This returns a date
   SpreadsheetApp.getUi().alert('From selected range: '+SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange(2, 1).getValue()); 

   // This also returns a date
   SpreadsheetApp.getUi().alert('From event range: '+e.range.getValue()); 
}
```

I'm sure there's a reason for this that I'm just missing. Can somebody clue me in? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

**e.Value**

There is poor [documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events) about `e.value`, all it says is:

> New cell value after the edit. Only available if the edited range is a
>   single cell.

The real [values of dates in spreadsheets](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/datetime.htm) are their serial numbers, starting from 1/1/1900. And only formattind is making dates look like dates in spreadsheets. So, I guess, this is a good feature that we can access this value with `e.value`

---

**range.getValue()**

There's [more info](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getValue()) about this function, it gives:

> Number, Boolean, Date, or String depending on the value of the cell

So it works ok, giving a date. But Google Apps is using javascript which [treats dates differently](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_dates.asp). And this may cause problems with understanding of dates.